# Export private/public keys from X509 certificate to PEM

Tags: c#, .net-core, pem, x509certificate2

is there any convenient way to export private/public keys from .p12 certificate in PEM format using .NET **Core**? Without manipulating with bytes at low level? I googled for hours and almost nothing is usable in .net core or it isn't documented anywhere..

Let's have an X509Certificate2

```
var cert = new X509Certificate2(someBytes, pass);
var privateKey = cert.GetRSAPrivateKey();
var publicKey = cert.GetRSAPublicKey();
// assume everything is fine so far
```

And now I need to export the keys as two separate PEM keys. I already tried `PemWriter` in BouncyCastle but the types are not compatibile with System.Security.Cryptography from Core... no luck.

In other words, I'm finding a way how to write this:

```
$ openssl pkcs12 -in path/to/cert.p12 -out public.pub -clcerts -nokeys
$ openssl pkcs12 -in path/to/cert.p12 -out private.key -nocerts
```

Does anybody have an idea?

Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/search?utf8=✓&q=pem&type= The knowledge is hidden in the GitHub issues and code. If you could not dig that out easily, you can create a new issue and discuss with who develop that.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

**Update (2021-01-12)**: For .NET 5 this is pretty easy. .NET Core 3.0 can even get most of the way there.  The original answer was written when .NET Core 1.1 was the newest version of .NET Core.  It explains what these new methods are doing under the covers.

**Update (2023-08-30)**: And .NET 7 added the direct-to-PEM methods, making the PEM output even easier.

### .NET 7+:

```
string certificatePem = cert.ExportCertificatePem();

AsymmetricAlgorithm key = cert.GetRSAPrivateKey() ?? cert.GetECDsaPrivateKey();
string pubKeyPem = key.ExportSubjectPublicKeyInfoPem();
string privKeyPem = key.ExportPkcs8PrivateKeyPem();
```

.NET 7 also added PemEncoding.WriteString, letting the .NET 5-style code go to `string` instead of `char[]`.

### .NET 5+:

```
byte[] certificateBytes = cert.RawData;
char[] certificatePem = PemEncoding.Write("CERTIFICATE", certificateBytes);

AsymmetricAlgorithm key = cert.GetRSAPrivateKey() ?? cert.GetECDsaPrivateKey();
byte[] pubKeyBytes = key.ExportSubjectPublicKeyInfo();
byte[] privKeyBytes = key.ExportPkcs8PrivateKey();
char[] pubKeyPem = PemEncoding.Write("PUBLIC KEY", pubKeyBytes);
char[] privKeyPem = PemEncoding.Write("PRIVATE KEY", privKeyBytes);
```

`new string(char[])` can turn those char arrays into `System.String` instances, if desired.

For encrypted PKCS#8 it's still easy, but you have to make some choices for how to encrypt it:

```
byte[] encryptedPrivKeyBytes = key.ExportEncryptedPkcs8PrivateKey(
    password,
    new PbeParameters(
        PbeEncryptionAlgorithm.Aes256Cbc,
        HashAlgorithmName.SHA256,
        iterationCount: 100_000));
```

### .NET Core 3.0, .NET Core 3.1:

This is the same as the .NET 5 answer, except the `PemEncoding` class doesn't exist yet.  But that's OK, there's a start for a PEM-ifier in the older answer (though "CERTIFICATE" and `cert.RawData`) would need to come from parameters).

.NET Core 3.0 was the release where the extra key format export and import methods were added.

### .NET Core 2.0, .NET Core 2.1:

The same as the original answer, except you don't need to write a DER encoder.  You can use the [System.Formats.Asn1 NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Formats.Asn1/).

### Original answer (.NET Core 1.1 was the newest option):

The answer is somewhere between "no" and "not really".

I'm going to assume that you don't want the p12 output gunk at the top of `public.pub` and `private.key`.

`public.pub` is just the certificate. The `openssl` commandline utility prefers PEM encoded data, so we'll write a PEM encoded certificate (note, this is a certificate, not a public key.  It *contains* a public key, but isn't itself one):

```
using (var cert = new X509Certificate2(someBytes, pass))
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.AppendLine("-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----");
    builder.AppendLine(
        Convert.ToBase64String(cert.RawData, Base64FormattingOptions.InsertLineBreaks));
    builder.AppendLine("-----END CERTIFICATE-----");

    return builder.ToString();
}
```

The private key is harder.  Assuming the key is exportable (which, if you're on Windows or macOS, it isn't, because you didn't assert `X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable`) you can get the parameters with `privateKey.ExportParameters(true)`.  But now you have to write that down.

An RSA private key gets written into a PEM encoded file whose tag is "RSA PRIVATE KEY" and whose payload is the ASN.1 ([ITU-T X.680](https://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-X.680-201508-I/en)) RSAPrivateKey (PKCS#1 / [RFC3447](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447#appendix-A.1.2)) structure, usually DER-encoded ([ITU-T X.690](https://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-X.690-201508-I/en)) -- though since it isn't signed there's not a particular DER restriction, but many readers may be assuming DER.

Or, it can be a PKCS#8 ([RFC 5208](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5208)) PrivateKeyInfo (tag: "PRIVATE KEY"), or EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo (tag: "ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY"). Since EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo wraps PrivateKeyInfo, which encapsulates RSAPrivateKey, we'll just start there.

```
  RSAPrivateKey ::= SEQUENCE {
      version           Version,
      modulus           INTEGER,  -- n
      publicExponent    INTEGER,  -- e
      privateExponent   INTEGER,  -- d
      prime1            INTEGER,  -- p
      prime2            INTEGER,  -- q
      exponent1         INTEGER,  -- d mod (p-1)
      exponent2         INTEGER,  -- d mod (q-1)
      coefficient       INTEGER,  -- (inverse of q) mod p
      otherPrimeInfos   OtherPrimeInfos OPTIONAL
  }
```

Now ignore the part about otherPrimeInfos.  `exponent1` is DP, `exponent2` is DQ, and `coefficient` is InverseQ.

Let's work with a [pre-published 384-bit RSA key](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/25c5c8e1c9730651e7d4e0b0db5a881c94966bb7/src/Common/tests/System/Security/Cryptography/AlgorithmImplementations/RSA/TestData.cs#L22-L76).

RFC 3447 says we want Version=0.  Everything else comes from the structure.

```
// SEQUENCE (RSAPrivateKey)
30 xa [ya [za]]
   // INTEGER (Version=0)
   02 01
         00
   // INTEGER (modulus)
   // Since the most significant bit of the most significant content byte is set,
   // add a padding 00 byte.
   02 31
         00
         DA CC 22 D8 6E 67 15 75 03 2E 31 F2 06 DC FC 19
         2C 65 E2 D5 10 89 E5 11 2D 09 6F 28 82 AF DB 5B
         78 CD B6 57 2F D2 F6 1D B3 90 47 22 32 E3 D9 F5
   // INTEGER publicExponent
   02 03
         01 00 01
   // INTEGER (privateExponent)
   // high bit isn't set, so no padding byte
   02 30
         7A 59 BD 02 9A 7A 3A 9D 7C 71 D0 AC 2E FA 54 5F
         1F 5C BA 43 BB 43 E1 3B 78 77 AF 82 EF EB 40 C3
         8D 1E CD 73 7F 5B F9 C8 96 92 B2 9C 87 5E D6 E1
   // INTEGER (prime1)
   // high bit is set, pad.
   02 19
         00
         FA DB D7 F8 A1 8B 3A 75 A4 F6 DF AE E3 42 6F D0
         FF 8B AC 74 B6 72 2D EF
   // INTEGER (prime2)
   // high bit is set, pad.
   02 19
         00
         DF 48 14 4A 6D 88 A7 80 14 4F CE A6 6B DC DA 50
         D6 07 1C 54 E5 D0 DA 5B
   // INTEGER (exponent1)
   // no padding
   02 18
         24 FF BB D0 DD F2 AD 02 A0 FC 10 6D B8 F3 19 8E
         D7 C2 00 03 8E CD 34 5D
   // INTEGER (exponent2)
   // padding required
   02 19
         00
         85 DF 73 BB 04 5D 91 00 6C 2D 45 9B E6 C4 2E 69
         95 4A 02 24 AC FE 42 4D
   // INTEGER (coefficient)
   // no padding
   02 18
         1A 3A 76 9C 21 26 2B 84 CA 9C A9 62 0F 98 D2 F4
         3E AC CC D4 87 9A 6F FD
```

Now we count up the number of bytes that went into the RSAPrivateKey structure. I count 0xF2 (242). Since that's bigger than 0x7F we need to use multi-byte length encoding: `81 F2`.

So now with the byte array `30 81 F2 02 01 00 ... 9A 6F FD` you could convert that to multi-line Base64 and wrap it in "RSA PRIVATE KEY" PEM armor. But maybe you want a PKCS#8.

```
  PrivateKeyInfo ::= SEQUENCE {
    version                   Version,
    privateKeyAlgorithm       PrivateKeyAlgorithmIdentifier,
    privateKey                PrivateKey,
    attributes           [0]  IMPLICIT Attributes OPTIONAL }

  Version ::= INTEGER
  PrivateKeyAlgorithmIdentifier ::= AlgorithmIdentifier
  PrivateKey ::= OCTET STRING
```

So, let's do it again...  The RFC says we want version=0 here, too. AlgorithmIdentifier can be found in [RFC5280](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.1.1.2).

```
// SEQUENCE (PrivateKeyInfo)
30 xa [ya [za]]
   // INTEGER (Version=0)
   02 01
         00
   // SEQUENCE (PrivateKeyAlgorithmIdentifier / AlgorithmIdentifier)
   30 xb [yb [zb]]
      // OBJECT IDENTIFIER id-rsaEncryption (1.2.840.113549.1.1.1)
      06 09 2A 86 48 86 F7 0D 01 01 01
      // NULL (per RFC 3447 A.1)
      05 00
   // OCTET STRING (aka byte[]) (PrivateKey)
   04 81 F5
      [the previous value here,
       note the length here is F5 because of the tag and length bytes of the payload]
```

Backfill the lengths:

The "b" series is 13 (0x0D), since it only contains things of pre-determined length.

The "a" series is now (2 + 1) + (2 + 13) + (3 + 0xF5) = 266 (0x010A).

```
30 82 01 0A  02 01 00 30  0D ...
```

Now you can PEM that as "PRIVATE KEY".

Encrypting it? That's a whole different ballgame.

Comment: It's a shame this does't have more upvotes, you put a lot of work into this great answer.

Comment: I have 2 errors with the code for .net 5.0. First one, It doesn't let me use the ?? operator and the second one, i can't export the privateBytes unless I open the certificate with Exportable:


var cert = new X509Certificate2(bytesEntrada, pass, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

Comment: Is it possible to use the .NET Core 5 PemEncoding.Write() with ASN.1 (ITU-T X.680) RSAPrivateKey (PKCS#1 / RFC3447) structure - i.e. a file with file whose tag is "RSA PRIVATE KEY"? It seems that the only way is PKCS#8.

Comment: @acarlon Yep. It’s up to you to pass in the RSAPrivateKey value (e.g. `rsa.ExportRSAPrivateKey()`), though. The PEM encoder doesn’t understand translation, it just does what you tell it. If something’s not working you’ll want to ask a question instead of use comments here.

Answer (score 8):

I figured out a solution that works well. I could not find an EXACT example of how to go from certificate store to pem file in windows.  Granted, this may not work for some certificates, but if you are working with one you have created yourself (for example, if you just need security between two machines you control that the end user won't see) this is a good way of going back to pem / pk (linux style).

I utilized the utilities found at http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/

```
X509Store certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

X509Certificate2 caCert = certStore.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "3C97BF2632ACAB5E35B48CB94927C4A7D20BBEBA", true)[0];


RSACryptoServiceProvider pkey = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)caCert.PrivateKey;


AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keyPair = DotNetUtilities.GetRsaKeyPair(pkey);
using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("C:\\private.pem"))
{
    PemWriter pw = new PemWriter(tw);
    pw.WriteObject(keyPair.Private);
    tw.Flush();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

X509certificate2 -> Private, Public and Cert pems...I just discovered that you can do it in 5 or 6 lines of layman's code!

There is a free package called Chilkat (It has some chill branding). It has some very intuitive [Certificate Classes](https://www.chilkatsoft.com/refdoc/csCertRef.html) Here is some example code on how to create a self signed pfx formatted certificate and export it to PEM! So that is taking a `X509Certificate2` instance with a certificate and associated public key and the privatekey that signed it, and then exporting it as three separate Pem files. One for the certificate(includes public key), one for the public key, and one for the private key. Very easy (took a week of reading to figure this out, haha). And then checkout https://github.com/patrickpr/YAOG for a nice OpenSSL windows Gui for viewing/creating certs (as seen in the result screenshot).

```
using Chilkat;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;


namespace CertPractice
{
static public class CertificateUtilityExample
{

    public static X509Certificate2 GenerateSelfSignedCertificate()
    {


        string secp256r1Oid = "1.2.840.10045.3.1.7";  //oid for prime256v1(7)  other identifier: secp256r1
        
        string subjectName = "Self-Signed-Cert-Example";

        var ecdsa = ECDsa.Create(ECCurve.CreateFromValue(secp256r1Oid));

        var certRequest = new CertificateRequest($"CN={subjectName}", ecdsa, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256);

        //add extensions to the request (just as an example)
        //add keyUsage
        certRequest.CertificateExtensions.Add(new X509KeyUsageExtension(X509KeyUsageFlags.DigitalSignature, true));

        X509Certificate2 generatedCert = certRequest.CreateSelfSigned(DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(-1), DateTimeOffset.Now.AddYears(10)); // generate the cert and sign!
//----------------end certificate generation, ie start here if you already have an X509Certificate2 instance----------------


        X509Certificate2 pfxGeneratedCert = new X509Certificate2(generatedCert.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx)); //has to be turned into pfx or Windows at least throws a security credentials not found during sslStream.connectAsClient or HttpClient request...

        Chilkat.Cert chilkatVersionOfPfxGeneratedCert = new Chilkat.Cert(); // now use Chilcat Cert to get pems
        chilkatVersionOfPfxGeneratedCert.LoadPfxData(generatedCert.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx), null); // export as binary pfx to load into a Chilkat Cert

        PrivateKey privateKey = chilkatVersionOfPfxGeneratedCert.ExportPrivateKey(); // get the private key
        privateKey.SavePemFile(@"filepath"); //save the private key to a pem file
        
        Chilkat.PublicKey publicKey = chilkatVersionOfPfxGeneratedCert.ExportPublicKey(); //get the public key
        publicKey.SavePemFile(true, @"filepath"); //save the public key

        chilkatVersionOfPfxGeneratedCert.ExportCertPemFile(@"filepath"); //save the public Cert to pem file
        


        return pfxGeneratedCert;


    }
}
```

[image: Screen shot of output pem files]

Answer (score 1):

Based on @bartonjs knowledge ([his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43941142/8654564)), I have written a small class that should be easy to use.

So there is now also a complete example, without having to use external dlls/nuget packages

The only changes I had to make was:

- I had to add this "X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable" to the StorageFlags when creating the X509Certificate2 instance, so that the method "ExportPkcs8PrivateKey()" does not fail.

With my class it is possible to **convert Let's Encrypt certificates from PFX format to PEM format with certificate & private key**.

**How to use my class**

```
var certificateLogic = new CertificateLogic("fileName.pfx", "privateKeyOfPfx");
certificateLogic.LoadCertificate();
certificateLogic.GenerateSaveCertificatePem();
certificateLogic.GenereateSavePrivateKeyPem();
```

**My Code behind that class**

```
public class CertificateLogic {

    private readonly FileInfo CertificateFile;
    private readonly SecureString CertificatePassword;
    public X509Certificate2 Certificate { get; private set; }

    public CertificateLogic(FileInfo certificationFile, string password) {
        if (!certificationFile.Exists) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException(certificationFile.FullName);
        }

        CertificateFile = certificationFile;
        CertificatePassword = ConvertPassword(password);
    }

    public CertificateLogic(string certificationFullFileName, string password) {
        var certificateFile = new FileInfo(certificationFullFileName);
        if (certificateFile == null || !certificateFile.Exists) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException(certificationFullFileName);
        }

        CertificateFile = certificateFile;
        CertificatePassword = ConvertPassword(password);
    }

    private static SecureString ConvertPassword(string password) {
        var secure = new SecureString();
        foreach (char c in password) {
            secure.AppendChar(c);
        }

        return secure;
    }

    public void LoadCertificate() {
        LoadCertificate(X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
    }

    public void LoadCertificate(X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags) {
        Certificate = new X509Certificate2(CertificateFile.FullName, CertificatePassword, keyStorageFlags);
    }

    public byte[] GenerateCertificatePem() {
        var certData = Certificate.RawData;
        var newPemData = PemEncoding.Write("CERTIFICATE", certData);

        return newPemData.Select(c => (byte)c).ToArray();
    }

    public byte[] GeneratePrivateKeyPem() {
        var privateCertKey = Certificate.GetRSAPrivateKey();
        var privateCertKeyBytes = privateCertKey.ExportPkcs8PrivateKey();

        char[] newPemData = PemEncoding.Write("PRIVATE KEY", privateCertKeyBytes);

        return newPemData.Select(c => (byte)c).ToArray();
    }

    public FileInfo GenerateSaveCertificatePem() {
        var newData = GenerateCertificatePem();

        var oldFile = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(CertificateFile.FullName);
        var newCertPemFile = new FileInfo($@"{CertificateFile.DirectoryName}\{oldFile} Certificate.pem");
        return SaveNewCertificate(newCertPemFile, newData);
    }

    public FileInfo GenereateSavePrivateKeyPem() {
        var newData = GeneratePrivateKeyPem();

        var oldFile = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(CertificateFile.FullName);
        var newPrivateKeyPemFile = new FileInfo($@"{CertificateFile.DirectoryName}\{oldFile} PrivateKey.pem");
        return SaveNewCertificate(newPrivateKeyPemFile, newData);
    }

    public FileInfo SaveNewCertificate(FileInfo newFile, byte[] data) {
        File.WriteAllBytes(newFile.FullName, data);

        return newFile;
    }
}
```