# ECDsa Signing in .Net Core on Linux

Tags: apple-push-notifications, .net-core, ecdsa

I'm trying to create a C# implementation to send Pushes to Apple via their HTTP/2 APNS Endpoint with .Net core in Docker. Part of this requires sending an encrypted JWT Authorization Token along with the payload. With .Net core, I can sign the token when running on Windows, but when running in the Linux Docker image, it tips over loading the Key.

When running in the .net Core Docker Image, I get a platformnotsupported Exception on loading the key.

```
    public static string SignES256(string privateKey, string header, string payload)
    {

        // This is the failing Call
        CngKey key = CngKey.Import(Convert.FromBase64String(privateKey), CngKeyBlobFormat.Pkcs8PrivateBlob);

        using (ECDsaCng dsa = new ECDsaCng(key))
        {
            var unsignedJwtData =
                System.Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(header)) + "." + System.Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload));
            var unsignedJwtDataBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(unsignedJwtData);

            var signature =
                dsa.SignData(unsignedJwtDataBytes, 0, unsignedJwtDataBytes.Length, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256 );
            return unsignedJwtData + "." + System.Convert.ToBase64String(signature);
        }
    }
```

How can I do this from .Net Core on Linux?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

### Update: As of .NET Core 3.0, cross-platform PKCS is now built into the [framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.ecdsa.importpkcs8privatekey).

```cs
private static ECDsa GetEllipticCurveAlgorithm(string privateKey)
{
    var result = ECDsa.Create();
    result.ImportPkcs8PrivateKey(Convert.FromBase64String(privateKey), out _);
    return result;
}
```

### Original Answer:

As others have pointed out, BouncyCastle is a cross-platform alternative to Windows CNG. None of the other examples out there were quite working for me, though. Maybe this will help someone:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Portable.BouncyCastle" Version="1.8.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" Version="5.4.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

```cs
using System;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Security;

public class ApnsTokenProvider
{
    private readonly JwtSecurityTokenHandler _tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

    // Turn off caching so TokenHandler doesn't try to reuse disposed algorithms.
    private readonly CryptoProviderFactory _signingFactory = new CryptoProviderFactory
    {
        CacheSignatureProviders = false
    };

    public string GetToken(string teamId, string keyId, string privateKey)
    {
        using (var algorithm = GetEllipticCurveAlgorithm(privateKey))
        {
            var credentials = new SigningCredentials(new ECDsaSecurityKey(algorithm)
            {
                KeyId = keyId,
                CryptoProviderFactory = _signingFactory
            }, SecurityAlgorithms.EcdsaSha256);

            return _tokenHandler.CreateEncodedJwt(new SecurityTokenDescriptor
            {
                Issuer = teamId,
                SigningCredentials = credentials
            });
        }
    }

    private static ECDsa GetEllipticCurveAlgorithm(string privateKey)
    {
        var keyParams = (ECPrivateKeyParameters)PrivateKeyFactory
            .CreateKey(Convert.FromBase64String(privateKey));

        var q = keyParams.Parameters.G.Multiply(keyParams.D).Normalize();

        return ECDsa.Create(new ECParameters
        {
            Curve = ECCurve.CreateFromValue(keyParams.PublicKeyParamSet.Id),
            D = keyParams.D.ToByteArrayUnsigned(),
            Q =
            {
                X = q.XCoord.GetEncoded(),
                Y = q.YCoord.GetEncoded()
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: ImportPkcs8PrivateKey works on my Windows computer but fails on Windows Server for me. I had to use the BouncyCastle version.

Answer (score 5):

ECDsaCng is an ECDSA implementation using Windows CNG.  It's specific to Windows, so not supported on Linux.

The cross-platform way to do this would be

```
using (ECDsa ecdsa = ECDsa.Create())
{
    ecdsa.ImportParameters(Pkcs8ToParameters(privateKey));

    // the stuff in your current using 
}
```

Of course, PKCS#8 to ECParameters isn't the easiest thing in the world.  But we can give it a go.  In [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43941142/6535399) there's a breakdown of building a PKCS#8 for RSA.

Let's take this blob:

```
308187020100301306072A8648CE3D020106082A8648CE3D030107046D306B02
0101042070A12C2DB16845ED56FF68CFC21A472B3F04D7D6851BF6349F2D7D5B
3452B38AA144034200048101ECE47464A6EAD70CF69A6E2BD3D88691A3262D22
CBA4F7635EAFF26680A8D8A12BA61D599235F67D9CB4D58F1783D3CA43E78F0A
5ABAA624079936C0C3A9
```

It breaks down like

```
30 /* SEQUENCE */
   81 87 (payload is 0x87 bytes)

   02 /* INTEGER */ 01 (1 byte) 00 // Integer: 0. // validate this

   30 /* SEQUENCE */ 13 (0x13 bytes)

      06 /* OBJECT IDENTIFIER */ 07 (7 bytes)
         2A8648CE3D0201  (1.2.840.10045.2.1 / ecPublicKey) // validate this

      06 /* OBJECT IDENTIFIER */ 08 (8 bytes)
         2A8648CE3D030107 (1.2.840.10045.3.1.7 / secp256r1) // save this, curveName

   04 /* OCTET STREAM (byte[]) */ 6D (0x6D bytes)
      // Since the constructed (0x20) bit isn't set in the tag normally we stop here,
      // but we know from the ecPublicKey context that this is also DER data.

      30 /* SEQUENCE */ 6B (0x6B bytes)

         02 /* Integer */ 01 (1 byte) 01 // Integer: 1. // validate this.

         04 /* OCTET STREAM (byte[]) */ 20 (0x20 bytes / 256 bits)
            70A12C2DB16845ED56FF68CFC21A472B3F04D7D6851BF6349F2D7D5B3452B38A // save this: D

         A1 /* CONSTRUCTED CONTEXT SPECIFIC 1 */ 44 (0x44 bytes)

            03 /* BIT STRING (byte[] if the first byte is 0x00) */ 66 (0x66 bytes)

               00 // Oh, good, it's a normal byte[]. Validate this.

               // Formatting will become apparent. Save this.
               04
               8101ECE47464A6EAD70CF69A6E2BD3D88691A3262D22CBA4F7635EAFF26680A8
               D8A12BA61D599235F67D9CB4D58F1783D3CA43E78F0A5ABAA624079936C0C3A9
```

The BIT STRING at the end is "the public key". Since it starts with `04` (which it usually will, unless the sender is mad at you) it represents an "uncompressed point", meaning the first half of what's left is the X coordinate, and the remainder is the Y coordinate.  So from this structure you might get something like

```
string curveOid;

// You can decode the OID, or special case it.
switch (curveName)
{
    case "2A8648CE3D030107":
        // secp256r1
        curveOid = "1.2.840.10045.3.1.7";
        break;
    case "2B81040022"
        // secp384r1
        curveOid = "1.3.132.0.34";
        break;
    case "2B81040023":
        // secp521r1
        curveOid = "1.3.132.0.35";
        break;
    default:
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
 }

 return new ECParameters
 {
     Curve = ECCurve.CreateFromValid(curveOid),

     // We saved this.
     D = d,

     Q = new ECPoint
     {
        X = x,
        Y = y
     },
 }
```

This happens to be the key used in section D.1 (NIST P-256 / secp256r1) of [Suite B Implementer’s Guide to FIPS 186-3 (ECDSA)](https://www.iad.gov/iad/library/ia-guidance/ia-solutions-for-classified/algorithm-guidance/suite-b-implementers-guide-to-fips-186-3-ecdsa.cfm).

Since the EC key format is mercifully short on INTEGER values (which can require padding bytes) you can build a manual extractor for each keysize you want to support.  Or you can go the live DER reading route.  Or you can try to get your private key serialized in a more friendly form for your application.

Answer (score 0):

If your private key length is greater than 31 bytes, which it usually is, you need to get encoded X and Y in order for it to work.

Here is the code for this:

```
private static ECDsa GetEllipticCurveAlgorithm(string privateKey)
    {
        var keyParams = (ECPrivateKeyParameters)PrivateKeyFactory
            .CreateKey(Convert.FromBase64String(privateKey));

        var normalizedECPoint = keyParams.Parameters.G.Multiply(keyParams.D).Normalize();

        return ECDsa.Create(new ECParameters
        {
            Curve = ECCurve.CreateFromValue(keyParams.PublicKeyParamSet.Id),
            D = keyParams.D.ToByteArrayUnsigned(),
            Q =
        {
            X = normalizedECPoint.XCoord.GetEncoded(),
            Y = normalizedECPoint.YCoord.GetEncoded()
        }
        });
    }
```

Afterward, you can generate a token like this:

```
var signatureAlgorithm = GetEllipticCurveAlgorithm(privateKey);

            ECDsaSecurityKey eCDsaSecurityKey = new ECDsaSecurityKey(signatureAlgorithm)
            {
                KeyId = settings.Apple.KeyId
            };

            var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();   
            var token = handler.CreateJwtSecurityToken(
                issuer: iss,
                audience: AUD,
                subject: new ClaimsIdentity(new List<Claim> { new Claim("sub", sub) }),
                expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(5), 
                issuedAt: DateTime.UtcNow,
                notBefore: DateTime.UtcNow,
                signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(eCDsaSecurityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.EcdsaSha256));
```